# expected alert('hi') on DOM Ready?

Tags: javascript, jquery

With the following code:-  isn't there suppose to be an Alert message 'hi' when DOM becomes ready?

[here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sangramfuture/tzjW5/4/)

html:-

```
//including jquery
<script data-require="jquery@1.6.4" 
   data-semver="1.6.4" 
   src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.popbox').popbox(); // doesn't this execute the javascript function '$.fn.popbox' ?
  });
</script>



    <div class='popbox'> hi </div>
```

javascript included:-

```
(function(){
    $.fn.popbox = function(){    
     alert('hi');
    }
}).call(this)
```

Comment: Its probably loaded in teh wrong order. http://jsfiddle.net/tzjW5/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but on jsfiddle you set your javascript to run `onload` which is after domReady.

Here is a [working version](http://jsfiddle.net/tzjW5/6/).

Note: I added it to the head

Answer (score 1):

Looks your document ready isn't called at all. Maybe jquery didn't load? Check your console for errors (press F12 or control+shift+k in Firefox)

You could try this:

```
//including jquery
<script data-require="jquery@1.6.4" 
   data-semver="1.6.4" 
   src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div class='popbox'> hi </div>
<script>
  (function(){
    $.fn.popbox = function(){    
      alert('hi');
    }
  }).call(this)
  $('.popbox').popbox();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on where you include the "javascript included" part. On your JSFiddle, it's running *after* document.ready, so it's failing (check your console output).

That's basically because document.ready is a shortcut for the `DOMContentLoaded` event. That runs before the `window.onload` event, which is where your fiddle is adding the code on the JavaScript panel.